# PHP Referencing a specific array item from a form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, key

I know I found this once a few years ago but I can't find it again.

I have an HTML form that has groups of inputs that I have set up to arrays:

```
<label><input type='radio' name='choice1' value='K'>Keep</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice1' value='M'>Modify</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice1' value='D'>Delete</label>

<input name='1[ClassID]' type='text'> 
<input name='1[ClassTitle]' type='text'> 
<input name='1[ClassDate]' type='date' > 

<label><input type='radio' name='choice2' value='K'>Keep</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice2' value='M'>Modify</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice2' value='D'>Delete</label>

<input name='2[ClassID]' type='text'> 
<input name='2[ClassTitle]' type='text'> 
<input name='2[ClassDate]' type='date' >
```

Now, I have my PHP set up to look for the Choice field and see what it reflects:

```
        foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
    {
        if (substr($field,0,strlen($field)-1) == "Choice")
        {
            switch ($value)
```

etc.

Here's my problem.  I want to find out what the values of the "ClassID", "ClassTitle" and "ClassDate" are for the input referenced in that array.  I was able to figure out which array with the following:

```
            $row = substr($field,strlen($field)-1,strlen($field));
```

But now I want to find out the $_Post value of $row["ClassID"].  I've tried several things:

```
$row["ClassID"]
```

Gives me the $row

```
$_POST[$row["ClassID"]]
```

Gives me Array

```
$_POST[$row]["ClassID"]
```

Gives me an error.  ARGGHHH!  How do I get the ClassID?

Thanks

Comment: its working on my end. can u post full code

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your HTML like this:

Look at the changes `name='ClassID[1][]'`....

```
<label><input type='radio' name='choice1' value='K'>Keep</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice1' value='M'>Modify</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice1' value='D'>Delete</label>

<input name='ClassID[1][]' type='text'> 
<input name='ClassTitle[1][]' type='text'> 
<input name='ClassDate[1][]' type='date' > 

<label><input type='radio' name='choice2' value='K'>Keep</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice2' value='M'>Modify</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='choice2' value='D'>Delete</label>

<input name='ClassID[2][]' type='text'> 
<input name='ClassTitle[2][]' type='text'> 
<input name='ClassDate[2][]' type='date' >
```

**Posted Output**

```
Array
(
    [choice1] => K
    [ClassID] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a2
                )

        )

    [ClassTitle] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b2
                )

        )

    [ClassDate] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2016-12-30
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2016-05-19
                )

        )

    [choice2] => M
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching that suffix number into those `Class*` inputs, why not just group them as a whole row instead. Its naming group convention should look something like this:

```
input[1][choice]
input[1][ClassID]
input[1][ClassTitle]
input[1][ClassDate]
.. and another batch with input[2] and so on
```

The markup in this form should look like:

```
<label><input type='radio' name='input[1][choice]' value='K'>Keep</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='input[1][choice]' value='M'>Modify</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='input[1][choice]' value='D'>Delete</label>

<input name='input[1][ClassID]' type='text'> 
<input name='input[1][ClassTitle]' type='text'> 
<input name='input[1][ClassDate]' type='date' > 
<br/><br/>
<label><input type='radio' name='input[2][choice]' value='K'>Keep</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='input[2][choice]' value='M'>Modify</label><br> 
<label><input type='radio' name='input[2][choice]' value='D'>Delete</label>

<input name='input[2][ClassID]' type='text'> 
<input name='input[2][ClassTitle]' type='text'> 
<input name='input[2][ClassDate]' type='date' >
```

So that in turn, you'll already get the whole row, no more matching and other stuff:

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
```

This should yield:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [choice] => K
            [ClassID] => 1
            [ClassTitle] => 1
            [ClassDate] => 2016-11-11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [choice] => M
            [ClassID] => 2
            [ClassTitle] => 2
            [ClassDate] => 2016-02-22
        )

)
```

Then do the other stuff that you need to do:

```
foreach($input as $key => $value) {
    $key === 1, 2 etc..
    echo $value['ClassID'] corresponds to this current batch iteration
    echo $value['choice'] // the checkbox
    // your other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the terrific answers.  I actually FINALLY figured out the solution.

```
$rowarray = $_POST[$row];
```

I can now access the information for that particular row thus:

```
$rowarray["ClassID"]
```

Now others who stumble across this problem will have multiple solutions.